# http запрос в корутине

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine

Для своих целей я использую khttp, т. к. он подходит под меня. Попробовал сделать запрос - не вышло (вылетало приложение). немного почитав о данной проблеме, я сделал вывод, что мне необходимо сделать все не в основном потоке. Нашел информацию о корутинах и на основе примеров в интернете сделал это:

> MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        
        val otherClass = OtherClass() // инициализация класса ниже
 
        val button: Button = findViewById(R.id.request_button)
        val text_view: TextView = findViewById(R.id.result_text)
 
        button.setOnClickListener {
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val result = otherClass.getRequest("https://ru.stackoverflow.com")
                text_view.text = result
            } 
        } 
    }
}
```

> тот самый класс OtherClass

```
class OtherClass {
    suspend fun getRequest(url: String) : String {
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { khttp.get(url).text } 
    }
}
```

Это все я сделал из одного примера, который я нашел в интернете, но к сожалению приложение все так же вылетает.
Помогите, пожалуйста, решить данную проблему..

> LogCat

```
2021-11-12 19:08:13.139 1596-1596/com.company.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.company.myapplication, PID: 1596
    java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: No field host in class Ljava/net/URL; (declaration of 'java.net.URL' appears in /apex/com.android.art/javalib/core-oj.jar)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Native Method)
        at khttp.requests.GenericRequest.toIDN(GenericRequest.kt:198)
        at khttp.requests.GenericRequest.makeRoute(GenericRequest.kt:208)
        at khttp.requests.GenericRequest.<init>(GenericRequest.kt:132)
        at khttp.KHttp.request(KHttp.kt:60)
        at khttp.KHttp.get(KHttp.kt:30)
        at khttp.KHttp.get$default(KHttp.kt:29)
        at com.company.myapplication.OtherClass.getRequest(OtherClass.kt:11)
        at com.company.myapplication.MainActivity$onCreate$1$2.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:42)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8595)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

Comment: что пишет logcat? добавьте ошибку в вопрос

Comment: @IR42 обновил добавив ошибку

Comment: судя по всему бага в либе, https://github.com/ascclemens/khttp/issues/29, либа заброшена, переезжайте на другую, okhttp например

Comment: @IR42 понял, спасибо

Comment: Автор библиотеки нигде явно не декларирует, что на вообще совместима с Android runtime.